# Is it safe to point multiple websites at the same Asp.Net Identity user database?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, identity

I have two sites that are completely different domains but which I want to share the same user database. **I don't mind users having to actually log in to each site separately** and **I don't want users to go to some third SSO sign-on page**; I simply want it to work such that if you have an account on Site A, you automatically have an account on Site B, and vice versa.

Also, my two sites are an ASP.NET MVC 5 site and an ASP.NET Core 2 site, so the actual version of ASP.NET Identity package being used is different between the sites.

Right now I have them experimentally pointed at the same Identity user database, and it seems to work fine. My only concern is that I notice a `KeyVersion` column in the database, and I'm a little worried that at some point, one of the consumers of the database might upgrade the data in a way that the other version doesn't understand.

Is that an issue? And are there any other gotchas here I need to be aware of?